# Unexpected login screen appears when I try to visit my application start page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed my first application to the Google App Engine standard. After several unsuccessfull attempts it finally started. But when I try to visit its start page I redirected to the login form (unfamiliar to me, so I suppose it was provided by GCP).
I cannot understand what is wrong with my application, did anybody have similar experience? Do anybody has any suggestions what could happen?

I migrate already working Spring Boot application to GCP cloud
Application type: Spring Boot 2
Authentication type: application-based, provided by Spring

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.chyslin</groupId>
    <artifactId>what-and-where</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>what-and-where</name>
    <description>Information collect and management system</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-gcp.version>1.1.2.RELEASE</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
        <app-engine-maven-plugin.version>1.3.2</app-engine-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Exclude any jul-to-slf4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.25-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${app-engine-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>what-where</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.app-id=whatnwhere-south-post-1336


spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=2

connection.host=google
connection.db.name=<database name>
connection.instance-connection-name=<connection name>
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${connection.host}/${connection.db.name}?cloudSqlInstance=${connection.instance-connection-name}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=Europe/Kiev
spring.datasource.username=<db user name>
spring.datasource.password=<db passord>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

view.grid.rows.per.page=10
view.grid.paging.neighbours=3
password.encoder.strength=11

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=<sender-account e-mail>
spring.mail.password=**********
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

spring.mvc.locale=uk_UA
spring.mvc.locale-resolver=fixed

lookup.batch.size=10

logging.file=${user.home}/what-where/server.log
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/liquibase/changelog.xml
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=WARNING
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=WARNING


security.token.validity.seconds=1209600

security.default.authentication.success.url=/user/profile/welcome
security.supervisor.authentication.success.url=/user/admin/list
security.administrator.authentication.success.url=/user/admin/list
security.operator.authentication.success.url=/vacancy/list
security.viewer.authentication.success.url=/user/profile/welcome
```

appengine-web.xml:

```xml
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>what-where</application>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <staging>
        <enable-jar-classes>true</enable-jar-classes>
    </staging>
</appengine-web-app>
```

app.yaml:

```
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 5

resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 2.3
  disk_size_gb: 10
  volumes:
    - name: ramdisk1
      volume_type: tmpfs
      size_gb: 0.5
```

application security configuration:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("***********************  Configure  *********************");
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/profile/**").hasRole(UserRole.VIEWER.name())
                .antMatchers("/user/admin/**").hasRole(UserRole.SUPERVISOR.name())
                .antMatchers("/vacancy/manage/**").hasAnyRole(UserRole.OPERATOR.name(), UserRole.ADMINISTRATOR.name(), UserRole.SUPERVISOR.name())
                .antMatchers("/dwelling/manage/**").hasAnyRole(UserRole.OPERATOR.name(), UserRole.ADMINISTRATOR.name(), UserRole.SUPERVISOR.name())
                .antMatchers("/api/**/save").hasAnyRole(UserRole.OPERATOR.name(), UserRole.ADMINISTRATOR.name(), UserRole.SUPERVISOR.name())
                .antMatchers("/api/**/delete").hasAnyRole(UserRole.OPERATOR.name(), UserRole.ADMINISTRATOR.name(), UserRole.SUPERVISOR.name())
                .antMatchers("/master/**/list").hasAnyRole(UserRole.OPERATOR.name(), UserRole.ADMINISTRATOR.name(), UserRole.SUPERVISOR.name())
                .antMatchers("/master/**/add").hasAnyRole(UserRole.OPERATOR.name(), UserRole.ADMINISTRATOR.name(), UserRole.SUPERVISOR.name())
                .antMatchers("/history/**").hasAnyRole(UserRole.ADMINISTRATOR.name(), UserRole.SUPERVISOR.name())
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/user/authentication/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("login")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .failureUrl("/user/authentication/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/profile/welcome", false)
                .successHandler(successHandler())
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
                .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
                .tokenValiditySeconds(tokenValiditySeconds)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
        ;
    }
```

I expect the landing page of my application will be loaded but instead I'm redirected to the mentioned login page (and cannot suppose which creadentials I have to provide to it): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yskq1.png

Comment: You should antMatcher something like this one:
`.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()`
 If we assume that root url is your landing page.

Comment: what is the url of your landing page? might be under a secured path

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I created the problem  by myself when trying avoid another one: spring factory fails to find any repository interfaces: I moved all configuration stuff from application class to separate configuration and it seems that application context wasn't initialized in app engine at all.

But problem with repository scan still isn't solved.

Comment: If your issue is solved but you have some other questions, you should specify this new issue either editing your question or just creating a new post.

Answer (score 0):

I found a source of all problems: it was the following block in appengine-web.xml:

```xml
<staging>
        <enable-jar-classes>true</enable-jar-classes>
</staging>
```

It caused Spring Jpa failed to locate repository interfaces.

Comment: Hey Mykola!

If your answers worked out for you, could you accept the one that is related to the main issue of your post? That way it will get better visibility and will help other users with similar issues =)!